# Creating a hole in a <div> element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Definition of *Hole in a div* - An element or a method by which you can show the background, only for a particular area, behind the content of a `<div>` element.

Comment: you mean creating a mask? best thing would split the div up in portions and make the opacity 0 in the part where you want to unmask

Comment: Not like a mask, something like a see through lens.

Comment: k but my answer stays the same split the div up in portions and make the opacity 0 in the part where you want to lens :P

Comment: Its going to be really difficult splitting that div up man, there has to be another way.

Comment: Is it an option to create a GIF with a transparent area and use this as background-image of the div(background-color of the div has to be set to transparent)?

Comment: Yeah, then after that? How do we make it seethrough in a particular area?

Comment: nope trust me when i say it's not possible, you have to see a page as layers of boxes where you can do anything to the entire box but nothing with just a portion of it

Comment: Hmmmm... maybe the background of this div element can be broken into smaller boxes... and I can achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: could you possible show us your page and maybe tell us what you want to be able to see through the lens

Comment: regarding to my comment above: the transparent area of the background-image will be the area you can see trough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The larger issue is not actually the background of the element you want to see through (which would just be background-color:transparent) but instead its ancestor element(s). For instance, a div with a background-color: transparent is still going to look as if it has a white background if its containing element has a white background. The best approach then is to define the background colors at lower levels in the page. For instance, if you want to see through div#see-through and it's a child of div#content which is in between div#header and div#footer, you could give #header and #footer background colors but define #content as transparent. Then assign background colors to the individual sibling elements of #see-through. One more thing: it might be helpful to remember when defining the transparent element that even a transparent element can have "colored" borders, meaning that you might be able to reach into in-between spots without adding extra elements.

Comment: Just asking, is it possible to cut a hole through an element with having the element a background color gradient?

Answer (score 60):

CSS `box-shadow` is supported in almost all modern browsers, so you can do what you want (I hope, I understood you right) this way:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hole {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Fox_Head.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="hole"></div>
```

So, the block will be transparent, and all around it will be highlighted with its shadow.

Comment: or you can use outline:

"outline: 99999px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);"

Comment: Best solution so far.

Comment: @equinox outline-width appears to max out at 65534px on Chrome version 40.0, so "outline: 65534px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)" is fine, but higher values of outline-width result in no outline. There's a similar, though higher, limit with FF, too.

Comment: Outline seems not to support border-radius, it is block. Beware of using accidentally big blur radius eg. 0rem 0rem 4000rem 4000rem hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.6). In Mac Chrome Version 41.0.2272.104 (64-bit) causes significant slowness if background has eg. a table with few tens of cells. Scrolling and responsiveness to mouse is slow. Also it causes random rendering errors. Using blur radius 0 or outline is fast.

Comment: Making a huge box-shadow spread doesn't work on ios - disappears altogether when it exceeds some limit. equinox's solution: `outline: 9999px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);` works great on ios. Although, as Paul Pepper points out, `99999px` probably exceeds an outline limit... but why would anyone want an outline 100,000px???

Comment: On iOS Safari I see an upper limit of `box-shadow` combined with `border-radius: 50%` at `951px`. After that, it just disappears. The `outline` combined with `border-radius` does not work for me on iOS.

Comment: Instead of setting an impossible high size like 99999px, for my use case, `calc(100vw + 100vh)` worked pretty well (also on iOS).

Answer (score 38):

A new way to solve this, using blend modes, and supporting border-radius, multiple elements... but without support in IE

```css
.back {
 background-color: lightblue;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0px,lightblue 40px);
}

.base {
 position: relative;
 left: 10px;
 top: 10px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border: solid 1px black;
 background-color: white;
 mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.hole {
 width: 80px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 10px;
 border: solid 1px red; 
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
 <div class="base">
  <div class="hole">ONE</div>
  <div class="hole">TWO</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is some great information to know - I had not heard of `mix-blend-mode` beforehand. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is awesome, I agree, this is the best answer

Comment: @vals, Why is this only working with "gray" color for the Hole (any other color will not create a hole)???

Comment: @GilEpshtain the **hard-light** blend-mode , when the channel intensity is 0.5 (or 128 in rgb scale), will reproduce the color of the background. gray is 0.5 in all chanels, so it reproduces fully the background

Comment: It should be noted though that this **significantly decreases font quality** on both Firefox and Chrome (at least on Manjaro Linux) and that any color **other than `white`, `black`, `red`, `blue`, `lime`, `cyan`, `magenta` and `yellow`** become (partly) transparent. This affects not only the background color, but also text, borders, etc.

Comment: @vals what would be the solution if you wanted the **base** div to be of any other color, for example pink? also the children?

Comment: @simaghoreyshi You can not choose any color , only colors with RGB values of 0 or 255 are supported (so, red or green is ok, also yellow, but not pink)

Comment: @vals So we cannot have a pink div with a hole in it using this solution? that sucks. Thanks for the idea, though

Answer (score 13):

You can construct a set of frame divs in the following format:

[image]

So, one container div, with no/little style applied to it.

Then a set of 4 'border' divs with style applied to them, leavin the central area transparent.

Comment: Not what i was looking for, but i guess i can make your answer work. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem, I'm not sure if there is a way to take a generic div and punch holes in it, I think you have to do it this way I am afraid.

Comment: Google has once created something like that...  The hole followed your mouse as it moved over your site.  Check http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/12/introducing-google-browser-size.html

Comment: More like something i was searching for!

Comment: Making this work with round div, round hole (border-radius:50%) will be very hard to implement

Answer (score 4):

Found it!

1. Parent div with a relative position, a transparent background and
   hidden overflow.
2. Child div with absolute position, **with colored,
   super big borders to fill the background of the parent**, and a
   transparent background.

The hole will be composed of a transparent child, with borders so big they fill up the parent's background. The positioning of the child will depend of the size of the borders. Set a background to whatever is **behind** the parent, and it will show through!

In this example you can see the red through the yellow *faux* background (which is actually a huge border).

```
#parent{overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
#child {position:absolute; border:9000px yellow solid; top:0; left:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CarambaMoreno/UrbhS/

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a png with alpha channel transparency as the background image of your div.

```
<div style="background-image:url(pngwithtransparentarea.png);width:100px;height:100px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I designed something on code pen that I think you are/were looking for. I was looking for the same... couldn't find anything so this is what I made

[Demo](http://codepen.io/lucianadamson/pen/dfqBl)

Answer (score 2):

There's one approach, albeit it can only do mostly rectangular borders, with the following mark-up as a demo:

#### html:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="frame">
    </div>
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2232/2299184911_ea1091968b_z.jpg?zz=1" />
</div>
```

#### css:

```
#wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#frame {
    border: 60px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

[Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7J4XK/).

While there's no way to truly 'cut' a hole in a `div`, there is the possibility of using [`-webkit-mask-box-image`](http://webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/) to apply masks directly to images. Albeit this only works in, so far as I'm aware, Webkit browsers (I know that it's a `-webkit` vendor-prefixed property, but I don't believe that there's a `-moz` or `-o` equivalent, sadly).

[Demo using the above, `-webkit-mask-box-image` property, at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7J4XK/1/).

Comment: Hey David thanks though this is not what i wanted. Suppose your '#wrap', or any outside container had a background color. The code should've been able to penetrate through the image and show the background color of the outside container.

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa: ah, in which case I may have completely misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

After really thinking this through best thing i could come up with is if you use an iframe
it could be the "lens" that views whatever you desire but ofcourse it wont work like a real lens but close to

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to use an SVG element instead of a div, SVG provides a flexible mechanism for cutting holes using the `fill-rule="evenodd"` attribute. You can create as many transparent regions of any shape as you'd like.

Here's an example that cuts two square holes into a gray square (also available [as a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ubf9pv4/)):

```html
<img
  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Fox_Head.jpg"
  style="position: absolute; width: 300px;"
>

<svg style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
<!--
  This `path` element draws 3 squares:
    1. A gray 300x300 square
    2. A transparent 100x100 square
    3. Another transparent 100x100 square
  
  The key mechanism for creating transparent regions in the shape is
  `fill-rule="evenodd"`. This attribute affects pixel colors in the following
  way. Pick a pixel and draw an infinitely long line in any direction:
    - If the line crosses an odd number of lines, the pixel receives the fill
      color. In this fiddle, the infinite line extending from any gray pixel
      crossed an odd number of lines -- for example, just the line that is the
      perimeter of the gray rectangle.
    - If the line crosses an even number of lines, the pixel is transparent.
      In this fiddle, the infinite line extending from any transparent pixel
      crossed an even number of lines -- for example, the perimeters of the
      transparent square and the gray square.
-->
<path
  fill="grey"
  fill-rule="evenodd"
  d="
    M 0 0
    h 300
    v 300
    h -300
    Z
    
    M 25 50
    h 100
    v 100
    h -100
    Z
    
    M 175 50
    h 100
    v 100
    h -100
    Z
  "
/>
</svg>
```